# Why do I have to use : instead of the @ to pass a parameter in my WHERE SQL statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio-2012

Thank you in advance :)
I'm using SQL Plus as my database and Visual Studio 2013 as my front end. Everywhere online has the WHERE statement as

```
WHERE FNAME = @FNAME
```

to pass a parameter to

```
this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet2.DataTable1,fname1.Text);
```

but it doesn't work for me unless I do the

```
WHERE FNAME = :FNAME
```

when I'm building my queries in Visual Studio and cannot find documentation online and I want to add filters. I used mySQL before and I know how to do the easy filters when using @ in PHP/HTML.
Example I want to use wildcards % _:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers 
WHERE (FNAME Like @FNAME + '%')
```

but I've tried so same thing below in variations with no luck because I don't know why or the rules for : as a parameter

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE (FNAME Like :FNAME + '%')
```

Can someone point me to the right direction? Please let me know if you need more info.
Thank you and I apologize with the formatting to identify the SQL statements.

Comment: `:FNAME + '%'` is invalid SQL. The concatenation operator for strings (characters) is `||` in SQL. As for the rules on how parameters are used in PL/SQL: these are all well documented in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00806

Comment: It sounds to me like all the SQL examples for Visual Studio assume SQL Server. In T-SQL you would use `@` for variables and `+` for string concatenation. Oracle SQL is different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the link, I will look through the manual for the proper way to concatenate statements. Didn't know it was PL/SQL instead of SQL Plus.

Comment: @DavidFaber Thank you. I'm understanding now why people weren't having the same issue I was even though I was following the tutorials. I should of stayed with MySQL or use SQL Plus instead of Oracle, but it was setup for me to practice over the winter break and assume all SQL programming where the same when doing queries in Visual Studio.

Comment: SQL\*Plus is neither a programming language nor a query language. It's simply a command line client to access an Oracle database. You don't "choose" between SQLPlus and Oracle. If you use SQL\*Plus you also use Oracle (the database) The `||` operator is defined in the SQL86 standard. MySQL and SQL Server chose to ignore that standard when they implemented the `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, try something like:

```
$param = "myname%";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE FNAME LIKE :FNAME");
$stmt->bind_param("FNAME", $param);
```

So it will be evaluated as `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE FNAME LIKE 'myname%'`

In short, while passing parameter, pass it with wildcard and leave SELECT SQL clean with named parameter.